# Kafka maximum number of connections

Tags: apache-kafka

We are planning to implement Kafka to collect logs from all kind of devices.  We expect to have around 10k of devices.  Can we connect all these devices directly to a kafka cluster or should we funnel the logs through log servers to limit the number of connections to kafka?  We plan to have one topic per kind of devices (Linux, Aix, Windows 2003, 2008 and so on)
Thanks

Comment: Thank you Brian.  I've read this document.  The benchmarks have been done with just a couple of producers and consumers.  So it does not really answer the question on how many different connections it can manage.  My feeling is that there is no limit per se except may be a limit imposed by the O/S.

Comment: How many partitions per topic? What about a `devices` topic partitioned by device type? Or `nix-devices`, `windows-devices` topics? There's different ways you can slice the data

Comment: Jeeplaur I did some more digging and each connection to Kafka uses tcp sockets under the covers to communicate with each Kafka broker. These are light weight and can grow to any number as long as the Kafka broker has available memory for the connections. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Network. So I believe your good to go with regular brokers. Since Kafka scales linearly you can add more brokers and partitions to scale the load appropriately

Comment: Worth noting that on the consumer side, consumers poll for messages. Typically they poll with a timeout and will return as soon as there is a message to read. If you had, say, 1000 consumers all reading the same partition and msgs arriving on the partition at, say, 100 per second the broker potentially has up to 100k poll requests to serve per second. Which is a fair few. This will become a limiting factor, so, as mentioned above you would want to spread load across more partitions and brokers.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the relevant metric would be number of messages per second each Kaka node would need to deliver. It benchmarks very well, in the hundreds of thousands of messages per second per node, which scales linearly per node. If one or two nodes isn't enough you can always add more nodes to increase throughput.

A old benchmark with 3 nodes was doing 800k messages (~80 mb) per second, with each message being replicated to each other node.

You can read more in depth here:
https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

Edit:
Kafka connections are tcp connections under the covers:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Network

Quote:

```
Kafka uses a binary protocol over TCP. The protocol 
defines all apis as request response message pairs.
```

Tcp socket connections are pretty lightweight and limited only by the available memory of the server being connected to. Some Kafka scales linearly you should be able to scale out brokers and partion your topics for any load you anticipate